# Vref_cal on STM32F3xx ADC

Tags: microcontroller, adc, stm32, calibration, stm32f3

Is there a function to read the Vrefint_cal in Cubes HAL libraries? I'm using the F3xx.
I'd like to measure the supply voltage of the micro. The formula given in the reference manual is:

\$ \Large  VDDA = 3.3V \times \frac{Vrefint_{cal}}{Vrefint_{data}} \$

I've been searching through HAL (cube) and couldn't find a method to return the Vrefint_cal. The datasheet says that it is at `0x1FFF F7BA - 0x1FFF F7BB`, but I find it silly that there wouldn't be a method to read it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way is the following:

```
#define VREFINT_CAL_ADDR    0x1FFFF7BA

uint16_t vrefint_cal;                        // VREFINT calibration value
vrefint_cal= *((uint16_t*)VREFINT_CAL_ADDR); // read VREFINT_CAL_ADDR memory location
```

Or a more general is to simply create a pointer and assign `0x1FFFF7BA` to it, and then the rest is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define VREFINT_CAL_ADDR ((uint16_t*)((uint32_t)0x1FFFF7BA))
```

And then, for example:

```
Vdd = 3300*(*VREFINT_CAL_ADDR)/ADC_raw;
```

Where Vdd and ADC_raw are uint16_t.

More info here:
https://letanphuc.net/2016/07/stm32f0-adc/